# Convert Select2 input to tokens

Tags: jquery-select2

Does the [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) jQuery plug-in have a built-in function for converting strings to tokens?

I want to be able to call this tokenizing function when the user pastes strings into a Select2 field so that the pasted input becomes tokens.

Comment: You might need to elaborate. I know nothing of this "Select2", however, if you're using jQuery, the solution can't be hard. But also, are the "tokens" not strings?

Comment: I removed the "jquery" tag from the question as it relates to a specific plug-in. The "tokens" are strings represented as "blocks" in an auto-complete field.

Comment: Ah, so they are "objects"?

Comment: OIC! Kewl plugin!!! it looks nicer than the one i made! ouch! I'ma have a deeper look into it during my lunch break. I will try and help more when i have time. I love combo-box plugs!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have solved the question myself with the following code:

```
// force tokenizing of Select2 auto-complete fields after pasting
$('body').on('paste', '.select2-input', function() {
  // append a delimiter and trigger an update
  $(this).val(this.value + ',').trigger('input');
});
```

This assumes that commas are set as delimiters in the plug-in's "tokenSeparators" initialization setting.

Comment: This doesn't work for me (at least in firefox). `this.value` appears to be always empty.

Answer (score 1):

For 4.0.1 version:

```
$('#my-select').data('select2').dataAdapter.$search.val("tag1,tag2,").trigger("input");
```

This will add two tags: `tag1` and `tag2` (note trailing `,`).

Important: you should add `data: []` into `select2` init parameters.

Comment: This worked for me after changing the event being triggered to `keyup`.            `$j('#searchTerm').data('select2').dataAdapter.$search.val("tag1, tag2,").trigger("keyup");`

Answer (score 0):

Use an input type text, and assign the select2 to it. Like

```
<input type="text" id="makeTokens" />
```

and then in javascript

```
$("#makeTokens").select2({
  placeholder: "Paste data",
  tags: ["red", "green", "blue"],
  tokenSeparators: [",", " "]
});
```

in the tags, you can assign any values that you want it to display as select options and use the tokenSeperators to seperate the text on commas or spaces etc.

Note: The resultant input value will be comma seperated tokens.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Donald's solution didn't work for me (maybe newer versions of select2 behaves differently). This is what worked for me:

```
$('body').on('paste', '.select2-input', function (e) {
    var pasteData = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain') || '';
    $(this).val(pasteData + ',');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Since at the point the event was triggered the value of `.select2-input` was an empty string, I extractacted the pasted string from the event object. Apparently the default select2 for copying action was still triggering after this, so I had to add `e.preventDefault();` to stop it from running and messing up the input.

Answer (score 0):

just run this jQuery which takes the separatoes from `options.tokenSeparators` directly, and applies for all select2 instances in the page automatically:

```
$(document).on('paste', 'span.select2', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var select = $(e.target).closest('.select2').prev();
    var clipboard = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
    var createOption = function (value, selected) {
        selected = typeof selected !== 'undefined' ? selected : true;
        return $("<option></option>")
            .attr("value", value)
            .attr("selected", selected)
            .text(value)[0]
    };
    $.each(
        clipboard.split(new RegExp(select.data('select2').options.options.tokenSeparators.map(function (a) {
            return (a).replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
        }).join('|'))),
        function (key, value) {
            if (value && (!select.val() || (select.val() && select.val().indexOf('' + value) == -1))) {
                select.append(createOption(value));
            }
        });
    select.trigger('change');
});
```